# ADFS SSO integration - aspx exceptions

Tags: asp.net, adfs

We have implemented SSO on our web app and it's working fine. Users are redirected to the ADFS login before accessing our app and we accept the ADFS token and authenticate accordingly. We're happy.

The question is for some of the aspx pages, we don't require authentication. Is there a place to list those exceptions in the web.config (or other)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you can use the location tag with allow / deny.

Refer: [Setting authorization rules for a particular page or folder in web.config](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config).